# Android TableRow children issue

Tags: android, width, tablelayout, children, tablerow

I have a `TableLayout` with 3 rows at present and each row has one child, a `TextView`. My problem is that the `TextViews` widths do not `"match_parent"` as they should. I have followed the procedure of not defining heights and widths for them([like the documentation says](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.html)) but for some reason the problem is still there.

I have opened up the `hierarchyviewer` and had a look at the values, the `TableRow` fills the width as it should but the `TextView` does not fill the row, it is just wrapping the content. The full xml layout is below, does anybody have any ideas?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">   
    <TextView
        android:background="@drawable/textlines"
        android:text="@string/text1_string"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:padding="5dp">
    </TextView>
</TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">   
    <TextView
        android:background="@drawable/textlines"
        android:text="@string/text1_string"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:padding="5dp">
    </TextView>
</TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">   
    <TextView
        android:background="@drawable/textlines"
        android:text="@string/text1_string"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:padding="5dp">
    </TextView>
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Also I'll include the xml file for the `@drawable/textlines`. Perhaps the problem is in there? (The `textlines` code is taken from a solution provided on here concerning a question about borders) I pretty much understand it and I don't think it should affect my problem but I could be wrong. Anyway, here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
  <shape 
    android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#FF000000" />
        <solid android:color="#FFDDDDDD" />

    </shape>
</item>

<item android:top="1dp" android:bottom="1dp"> 
  <shape 
    android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#FFDDDDDD" />
        <solid android:color="#00000000" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't know why that happens but you could avoid that issue either by adding:

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

to your children `TextView`s, or by adding:

```
android:stretchColumns="0"
```

to your parent `TableLayout`.

Comment: @DanDar3 Yes, setting the width to 1 doesn't solve anything. Don't be afraid to edit a question/answer if you think you can correct it.

Comment: For streching all columns *programatically* use setStretchAllColumns(true);

Comment: You can try `android:stretchColumns="*"` via [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html#attr_android:stretchColumns)